# How to have a 3rd party application interact with flask

Tags: python, c#, flask, request

I have a 3rd party C# application that I would like to interact with a flask webapp I made. Basically, every time the C# application sends a POST request to flask, flask will get the request, make some changes, and refresh the page to update the changes.

However, right now what is happening is: Flask gets the request, makes changes, returns the HTML code to my application instead, and doesn't refresh the page. The data is changed, I can see it once I refresh the page. But I want flask to refresh the page when the data is changed.

Here is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/stats/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def display():
    global g_hours
    if request.method == "POST":
        g_hours = request.form["hours"]
        return redirect("/stats/")
    return render_template("statsOverview.html", hours=g_hours)
```

Here is my C# code:

```
 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
 var response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats/", content);
 var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Right now the redirect() returns the HTML code to my app instead of redirecting to the page (refreshing the page).

Answer (score 1):

Try `return redirect(url_for('display'))`

```
@app.route('/stats/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def display():
    global g_hours
    if request.method == "POST":
        g_hours = request.form["hours"]
        return redirect(url_for('display'))
    return render_template("statsOverview.html", hours=g_hours)
```